# How to delete the bland gap between nav and jumbotron in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am in trouble in my project for using bootstrap  nav.

After nav is jumbotron div, but there is a bland gap between nav and jumbotron.

I have trid define nav:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

"navbar-fixed-top" can delete bland gap, but nav has hidden part of jumbotron. So the content of jumbotron is not in the middle of container.

Here is my code:

```
 <style>
 .navbar .nav li.active a:hover{color:#51c3e1}
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid" style="height:70px">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="pic/logo.png" style="width:130px;height:40px;top:1px"></a>
</div>
<div></div>
</div>
</nav>  
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 style="white">Hello!</h1>
    <p style="white">I love this world!!</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems nothing wrong, who can help me?

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @Sarhang, I have got the solution, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

```
.navbar { margin-bottom:0px}
```